# Conversion between Fahrenheit and Celsius and vice versa with no loss

Tags: c#

The problem is that I have a `double` value representing Fahrenheit unit

```
var fahrenheit = 80.0;
```

To convert it to Celsius I use the formula

```
var celsius = (fahreheit - 32.0) / 1.8;
```

It gives a number `26.666667` (let's say `26.67`)

When I convert it back

```
var fahrenheitAgain = 1.8 * celsius + 32.0;
```

It gives a higher number `80.006` that is rounded to `80.01` if I have 2 decimal places. But how do I get the same value as before?

Is there any known solution to convert any double value back and forth to have always the same values?

Comment: Whatever you do to ensure that the numbers you've chosen here work out fine will just mean that it won't work out fine for different types of numbers.  If you actually have measured temperatures, then you need to realize that your values aren't actually exist in the first place, they're approximate, and treat them accordingly.

Comment: You can also use decimal rather than double. But as Servy said the problem will still occur for some values.

Comment: Should I understand that like there's no way to have the same values?

Comment: Yes. You can always store both values that way it will be as accurate as possible. That will take up more space though.

Comment: @deathismyfriend, decimals seem to solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot replicate your results - are you storing the intermediate values in some way that it loses precision?

Comment: Depending on the numbers you specify you WILL lose precision. Its something you either 1. accept, or 2. build a data structure that knows the base celsius and fahrenheit

Comment: @D Stanley, I'm storing in variables, nothing else. It doesn't lose precision actually, it is rounded while output

Comment: __Decimals will not solve the problem.__ There is no __general__ solution. You need to understand the math and then store the data you need befoe you loose them. If your math does fractions, keep the numerator and the denominator as integers. Float and double can only store binary numbers, decimal only, yup, decimal numbers. 1/3 is neither..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> (let's say `26.67`)

Let's not.

You can't start a calculation with "let's say" and expect a result to be accurate. Indeed, 26.67 °C is **exactly** 80.006 °F (no rounding error), so there is no possible way from that point on to get a more precise result.

Don't do "let's say"; store your results as precisely as you can, separate from code that displays them, and round for display only at the last moment.

There'll still be inaccuracies, as there are values that can't be fit within `double` (or `decimal` or any other such type) precisely, but you'll be affected by them less often, and often the effects won't be visible at all even when they're there.

Comment: My excuses for not being clear, by "let's say" I mean that I preserve the result in a string in {0.00} format, so I indeed have the exact value of 26.67 parsed from string to convert back.

Comment: In that case the problem comes with the domain, not the programming; 26.67 °C is 80.006 °F.

Answer (score 3):

Have a data structure that only does the conversion for display purposes, rather than converting it each time. So you only do the conversion once.

e.g.

```
public interface ITemperature
{
    double Celsius { get; }
    double Fahrenheit { get; }
}


public class CelsiusTemperature : ITemperature
{
    private readonly int _value;

    public CelsiusTemperature(int value)
    {
        this._value = value;
    }

    public double Celsius
    {
        get { return _value; }
    }

    public double Fahrenheit
    {
        get { return 1.8 * _value + 32.0; }
    }
}

public class FahrenheitTemperature : ITemperature
{
    private readonly int _value;

    public FahrenheitTemperature(int value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public double Celsius
    {
        get { return (_value - 32.0)/1.8; }
    }

    public double Fahrenheit
    {
        get { return _value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way that I could see being able to preserve the precision exactly would be to store the values as fractions.

This is assuming you have the data in a fractional form (i.e. 80 1/8 deg.) to begin with.  If you are starting with decimal values, then there is not going to be any way to get the exact value while converting back and forth.

A quick search shows a couple of implementations that could possibly work:

On [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9078/Fraction-class-in-C) or on [Visual C# Kicks](http://www.vcskicks.com/code-snippet/fraction.php)